# python convert scrape results to strings to count them

Tags: python

I need to count similar labels from html. I already got all of them in text format but to count them I suppose I need to: 1. Unite them 2. Convert to strings 3. count. Does anyone can help with it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
html = """<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">&quot;amy in marketing press one amanda
in groups press two to repeat this menu press star&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">Labels:<FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Machine-Message,In-House-Alternative,Company-Alternative;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Machine-Message,</FONT><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Greetings-Other;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Machine-Message,</FONT>
<FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Personal-Information;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">@377, 136163000006,</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">&quot;thank you for calling quick help
a lot and grill press one for private party information press two for
to go orders press three for reservations&quot;</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><BR>
</P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in">Labels:<FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Machine-Message,Company-Type;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#00b050">Machine-Message,
Company-Type;</FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in"><FONT COLOR="#0070c0">Machine-Message,
Company-Type;</FONT></P>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
labels = soup.find_all('font', color="#ff0000")
for label in labels:
    print (label.text)
#print(Counter(labels which I want to count).most_common())
```

Comment: Why are you using `"""`? That means a multi-line comment, not a `String`.

Comment: I have big html file. And this part was extracted from there as example. Probably you are right about multi-line comment , I don't know how to call it. Is it possible to unite them into separated strings and then count similar?

Comment: @AMACB, `foo = """You must be kidding."""` Try it.

Comment: I need to learn it, cos I am new to the most of programming stuff

Comment: Wow, Python gets weirder and weirder :P